# Generate xml by changeset

Tags: c#, tfs

Is it possible to generate an xml file from the resulting change set in TFS? I need to query TFS and get a list of the change sets within a date range. I then must transform the TFS data into an xml file.

Comment: Yes, what have you done so far? TFS has a .Net/Java API as well as a REST API in later versions. The objects from the .Net API are probably won't serialize without some manual transformation. For the REST API, JSON -> XML might be possible. Please show your progress so far, and update the question if you have a specific problem.

Comment: Currently I have the projects setup to create the xml on build. Ideally I would be able to compare xml files from changeset to changeset on publicly exposed methods and comments resulting in ideal documentation. Transform xml into ExpandoObject and update Word file with correct documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Query changesets within a date range is easy. There are several ways to achieve this:

1. In Source Control Explorer, right click the file, and choose Find--Find changesets.
2. Install [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/), query the changesets under History sidekick.
3. Use [History command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh.aspx).
4. Use API.

But there is not a default way to generate the changesets list to a xml file. Alternative way will be:

1. Save the changesets list to a .csv file in Team Foundation Sidekicks, then convert .csv file to .xml file.
2. Use TFS API to get changesets list and transform it to a .xml file.

Comment: Perfect. Will look into doing so. Transformation using ExpandoObject for all xml to dynamic.

Comment: You can share us your experience once you have a solution works.